# NoNodeAvailableException elasticsearch in one IntelliJ project but not in other with same programmatic and elasticsearch.yml configuration and code

Tags: java, git, maven, elasticsearch, intellij-idea

I know question related to NoNodeAvailbleException has already been asked multiple times on this platform previously. I had followed through all the solutions been provided by experts previously; yet none work with me. The problem with the Exception I get is unique.

I am facing NoNodeAvailableException in my Java Client. The usual solution is to ensure consistency in confiurations been set through programmatically and the one present in elasticsearch.yml. I had already ensured this.

Just for being on the safe side, I had created another IntelliJ project with same Maven dependencies with same elasticsearch client code and same configurations, but I didn't get NoNodeAvailableException in it.

I could work with this new Intellij Project, by shipping code from my previous IntelliJ project but I will lose all the commits I had previously have and other services written in my old project.

Old client code:

```
public class ElasticSearchTest {

private static TransportClient client;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Settings elasticsearchSettings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch_cse").put("node.name","elasticsearch_cse_data").build();

        client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(elasticsearchSettings)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300))
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));


        String sampleWebsite = "www.samplewebsite.com";

        List<PageModel> pages = new ArrayList<PageModel>();
        pages.add(new PageModel("www.samplewebsite.com/page1", "darkknight wins a lot", "First page"));
        pages.add(new PageModel("www.samplewebsite.com/page1/page2", "superman survives", "Second page"));
        pages.add(new PageModel("www.samplewebsite.com/page3", "wonderwoman releases", "third page"));

        DomainModel domainModel = new DomainModel(sampleWebsite, pages);

        insertIndicesFromDomain(domainModel);

        boolean isResultFound = false;
        List<PageModel> pageModels = getSearchResults(domainModel, "superman");
        for(PageModel pageModel: pageModels){
            if(pageModel.getPageContent().equals("superman survives")){
                isResultFound = true;
                System.out.println(pageModel);
            }
        }


        // closeService();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public static void insertIndicesFromDomain(DomainModel domainModel){
    int i = 1;
    for(PageModel pageModel: domainModel.getPages()){
        client.prepareIndex("websiteindex", domainModel.getDomainName(), i + "").setSource(pageModel.getPageModelInMapFormat()).execute().actionGet();
        i += 1;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public static List<PageModel> getSearchResults(DomainModel domainModel, String searchKeyWords){
    SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch("websiteindex").setTypes(domainModel.getDomainName()).setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("content", searchKeyWords)).execute().actionGet();

    SearchHit[] results = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
    List<PageModel> pageModels = new ArrayList<PageModel>();
    for(SearchHit searchHit: results){
        pageModels.add(new PageModel(searchHit.getSource()));
    }

    return pageModels;
}

public static void getIndices(){
    ImmutableOpenMap<String, IndexMetaData> indicies = client.admin().cluster().prepareState().get().getState().getMetaData().getIndices();
    for(ObjectObjectCursor<String, IndexMetaData> entry: indicies){
        System.out.printf(entry.key + " " + entry.value);
    }
}

public static void closeService(){
    client.close();
}

}
```

StackTrace of old client code:

```
Exception in thread "main" NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{H90yHKj8R_aa0MeTciqjvA}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:347)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:245)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:59)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:363)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:408)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:80)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:54)
at net.media.sitesearch.models.ElasticSearchTest.insertIndicesFromDomain(ElasticSearchTest.java:66)
at net.media.sitesearch.models.ElasticSearchTest.main(ElasticSearchTest.java:42)
```

New client Code:

```
public class Main {

private static TransportClient client;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Settings elasticsearchSettings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch_cse").put("node.name","elasticsearch_cse_data").build();

        client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(elasticsearchSettings)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300))
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));


        String sampleWebsite = "www.samplewebsite.com";

        List<PageModel> pages = new ArrayList<PageModel>();
        pages.add(new PageModel("www.samplewebsite.com/page1", "darkknight wins a lot", "First page"));
        pages.add(new PageModel("www.samplewebsite.com/page1/page2", "superman survives", "Second page"));
        pages.add(new PageModel("www.samplewebsite.com/page3", "wonderwoman releases", "third page"));

        DomainModel domainModel = new DomainModel(sampleWebsite, pages);

        insertIndicesFromDomain(domainModel);

        boolean isResultFound = false;
        List<PageModel> pageModels = getSearchResults(domainModel, "superman");
        for(PageModel pageModel: pageModels){
            if(pageModel.getPageContent().equals("superman survives")){
                isResultFound = true;
                System.out.println(pageModel);
            }
        }


        // closeService();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public static void insertIndicesFromDomain(DomainModel domainModel){
    int i = 1;
    for(PageModel pageModel: domainModel.getPages()){
        client.prepareIndex("websiteindex", domainModel.getDomainName(), i + "").setSource(pageModel.getPageModelInMapFormat()).execute().actionGet();
        i += 1;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public static List<PageModel> getSearchResults(DomainModel domainModel, String searchKeyWords){
    SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch("websiteindex").setTypes(domainModel.getDomainName()).setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("content", searchKeyWords)).execute().actionGet();

    SearchHit[] results = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
    List<PageModel> pageModels = new ArrayList<PageModel>();
    for(SearchHit searchHit: results){
        pageModels.add(new PageModel(searchHit.getSource()));
    }

    return pageModels;
}

public static void getIndices(){
    ImmutableOpenMap<String, IndexMetaData> indicies = client.admin().cluster().prepareState().get().getState().getMetaData().getIndices();
    for(ObjectObjectCursor<String, IndexMetaData> entry: indicies){
        System.out.printf(entry.key + " " + entry.value);
    }
}

public static void closeService(){
    client.close();
}

}
```

Output of new client code:

```
2
3
4
PageModel{pageUrl='www.samplewebsite.com/page1/page2', pageContent='superman survives', pageTitle='Second page', map={title=Second page, url=www.samplewebsite.com/page1/page2, content=superman survives}}
```

The only difference between my old code and new code, is that old code is under Git working tree and the new one is not.

New edit:

I found another important difference between my two projects. In my new Intellij Project, I haven't shipped all the other services from old one and just kept necessary ElasticSearch Client code. Hence, the new Intellij Project did not contain all the dependencies of the old project, but only one dependency of the elasticsearch.
In my new client code which does not contain all the maven dependencies except for elastic search, I don't get NoNodeAvailableException. Could the dependencies between elastic search and other maven apis be an indirect reason for that exception?

New pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.sampleelasticsearch</groupId>
<artifactId>SampleES</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Old pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>net.media.siteresearch</groupId>
<artifactId>SiteSearch</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.media.crawler</groupId>
        <artifactId>MnetCrawler</artifactId>
        <version>0.995</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.24</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/ -->
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

If authors here want to check logs from elastic search server or any other, then please ask (I have not added them because the question details were already filled with a lot of other relevant snippets from my perspective. Also, the question details would get cluttered).

Comment: When making multiple edits to your questions, please be careful that the new reading order of your question is not more confusing than the last version - it certainly was the case here. There are two good strategies for adding new information to questions: (1) add it at the end, and make it very clear it is new information; (2) rewrite the question as if the new information was in the first edit all along. Since you do not have answers yet (and thus no answers can be invalidated by the change), approach (2) would have been fine, so I have removed the edit messages.

Comment: Thank you. Will edit the question and rearrange the order. Will keep this in mind.